# Ember #link-to is invalid, expecting ID or DATA

Tags: ember.js

I have a restaurants resource in an Ember application, which uses this for a template

```
 {{#each item in model}}
      <li> 
      {{ item.name }} 
     </li>
    {{/each}}
```

I wanted to change the list items to links so I did this (following instructions in the ember starterkit video)

```
  {{#each item in model}}
      <li> {{#link-to 'restaurant' this}}
      {{ item.name }} 
      {{/link-to }}</li>
    {{/each}}
```

I also created a route for a restaurant

```
this.resource("restaurants");
this.resource("about");
this.resource('restaurant', { path: ':restaurant_id'});
```

When I try to render the list of restaurants I now get this error  showing that it's not expecting the link

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 3:
...del}}      <li> {{ #link-to 'restaurant' thi
----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
```

Ladies and Gentlemen, have I given you enough information to identify the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want `item` instead of `this` in the `link-to`

```
{{#each item in model}}
  <li>
    {{#link-to 'restaurant' item}}
      {{ item.name }} 
    {{/link-to}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```